# How to load image to web-server using context menu

Tags: forms, registry, contextmenu, setup-project

I can add item to context menu that opens my site with file name as get-data after the click. But I want to use not file name, but file data, image for example, how to write it in registry, or somewhere else?

Comment: Do u use some framework? Can u show sample of ur site? It is not clear what u need for me. which language do u use?

Comment: I use .net, c#. I have a setup-project, I can change registry using it, for example add key : HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/SystemFileAssociations/image/shell/mykey/command and set default value to command like "firefox.exe http://google.com", I want to know how to put file-data into request

Answer (score -1, accepted):

set it to

firefox http://www.google.com?q=somedata

This what u need?

Comment: yes, but how to send image data, but not file name and so on.. i want to know is it possible to send image using post this way

Comment: To send image u need to use POST request. This request u need to prepare by some UserAgent Class. U cannot save it as GET URL in Registry. But I guess u can write some callback for ContextMenu in C# can it will be triggered every time user chose ur option in CM and ur C# code can send with POST any data.  I never writen in C# but sure it can be done with win32 API.